# Awesomium - Return Javascript Result to C#

Tags: c#, javascript, awesomium

Javascript / HTML Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function configurator(clicked) { 
return clicked.name;   
} 
</script>

<a name="link1" href="#" onclick="configurator(this)">Link 1</a>
<a name="link2" href="#" onclick="configurator(this)">Link 2</a>
```

I want to return the "clicked.name" value to let's say "result" variable in C# when onclick event on the link  triggered. I don't know how to do that. Could someone help me...

Note: I'm still very new to Awesomium :)

**Update:**

I follow @JonnyReeves method with a little modified:

```
using (JSObject myGlobalObject = webControl1.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("myGlobalObject"))
{
    myGlobalObject.Bind("onLinkClicked", true, (sen, eve) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(sen));
    });
}
```

but I got "Awesomium.Windows.Controls.WebControl" as result not the clicked link's name.

Comment: [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX). It is not possible to simply `return` data to the server, but you can make a separate request and pass the data along with it.

Comment: I'm not using any web server. I'm just using Awesomium (WebControl) as browser. I still learning how to exchanging data between C# and html (Awesomium).

Comment: Duplicate of accepted answer... : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089912/how-to-return-javascript-results-back-to-c-sharp-with-awesomium?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you you could make use of Awesomium's [`JSObject.bind`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=M_Awesomium_Core_JSObject_Bind) method to invoke a C# method from JavaScript.  A typical approach would be to expose a JavaScript global object which includes all your 'bridge' methods (ie: those that pass data between C# and JavaScript).

```
// Create and acquire a Global Javascript object.
// These object persist for the lifetime of the web-view.
using ( JSObject myGlobalObject = webView.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject( "myGlobalObject" ) )
{
    // The handler is of type JavascriptMethodEventHandler. Here we define it
    // using a lambda expression.
    myGlobalObject.Bind( "onLinkClicked", false, ( name ) =>
    {
        Debug.Print( String.Format( "User clicked: {0}", name ) );
    } );
}
```

You can now invoke this method from your JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function configurator(clicked) 
    { 
           myGlobalObject.onLinkClicked(clicked.name);
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code but got error on "Delegate 'Awesomium.Core.JavascriptMethodEventHandler' does not take 1 arguments" so I changed your code a little (see OP). But I can't get the clicked link's name (<a name="link1">).